# Difference between init and initWithBridge constructor while bridging?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have been going through docs and various examples to instantiate ios UI views in react-native

Simple One to make 100X100 square

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
- (UIView *)view {
   UIView * sampleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
   sampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   return sample
 }
```

But in some examples i get too see a method `initWithBridge` and return `instanceType` i understand that as constructor

but how does it differs from constructor `-init` and `-initWithBridge` ? and what is benefit of using `-initWithBridge`

Answer (score 0):

Benefit is that you can pass bridge instance(RCTBridge class) to the view. Most of the time you don't need to have access to bridge instance inside of view class, but sometimes you do.

Comment: HI Thanks, can you tell me what difference does this make ? If i initialize any Module with `initWithBridge` Does it mean accessing the event on the module using Module name instead of `DeviceEventEmitter`